# Why does my code read in 0 vowels when entering a string in the command line?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I am stuck on why my code doesn't count the number of vowels, including case-insensitive, and print a sentence reporting the number of vowels found in the word 'and'.

```
import sys

vowels = sys.argv[1]

count = 0 

for vowel in vowels:
   if(vowel =='a' or vowel == 'e' or vowel =='i' or vowel =='o' or vowel =='u' or vowel 
   =='A' or vowel =='E' or vowel =='I' or vowel =='O' or vowel =='U'):
      count += 1

if count == 0:
   print('There are 0 vowels in '.format(count))
elif count < 2:
   print('There is 1 vowel in '.format(count))
else:
   print('There are {} vowels'.format(count, vowels))
```

In my terminal:

**user$ python** vowel_counter.py and

There are 0 vowels in

There are 0 vowels in

Comment: Please dont edit the correct answer into your question - it invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 2):

sys.argv is a list of the running arguments, where the first element is always your running file. therefore, you do not iterate over the text but rather over the arguments ['vowel_counter.py', 'and'].

You should do something like this:

```
vowels=sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the major problems with your code is indentation, According to the way you've presented the code, the block that checks `count` is run on every iteration of your loop.

Secondly, you've not output the word you're checking which would have probably indicated the bug that you're reading the wrong argument. Here is some working code - although kept like your original there are much better ways to do this logic

```
import sys

vowels = sys.argv[1] 

count = 0 

for vowel in vowels:

   if(vowel =='a' or vowel =='i' or vowel =='o' or vowel =='u' or vowel 
   =='A' or vowel =='E' or vowel =='I' or vowel =='O' or vowel =='U'):

       count += 1

if count == 0:
  print('There are 0 vowels in {}'.format(vowels))
elif count < 2:
  print('There is 1 vowel in {}'.format(vowels))
else:
  print('There are {} vowels in {}'.format(count,vowels))
```

Note: you're missing `vowel =='e'` from your check.

Comment: I included the vowel == 'e' and changed vowels = sys.argv[1], but when I thought I fixed my indentation of count += 1,  my code still returns  "There is 1 vowel in" three times .

Comment: @python then its your indentation. Indentation is *really* important in python. Make sure the `if count == 0:` lines up with the `for`

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I am still confused though on how to return        $python vowel_counter.py and
There is 1 vowel in "and." I just started learning python and still not familiar with using .format

Comment: What do you mean by "return". You want your script to write to stdout?

Comment: Yeah I want my script to return the input command like 'and,' so when I type in my cmd line $ python vowel_counter.py and, it will return 'There is 1 vowel in "and."

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

The following will take care of single or multiple arguments passed in the command line. Like `python vowel_count.py foo` and `python vowel_count.py foo bar`

```
$ cat vowel_count.py
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]
print(args)
count = 0
for arg in args: # handling multiple commandline args
    for char in arg:
        if char.lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            count += 1

print("The {} contains {} vowels".format(' ',join(args), count))
```